# Machine Learning on Body-Brain prediction dataset

Tags: python, scikit-learn, prediction

I've separate training and test datasets which hold informations about brain and body weights. What I want to do is to predict brain weight in test dataset by given body weight in test dataset after learning from training dataset. I've done `linear regression` but the data didn't give a acceptable results because data isn't smoothly distributed.

How can we train "training dataset" by using `scikit-learn` in order to predict a single column of test dataset? Arrays below are for just demonstration.

```
    Training['Brain'] = [3.385, .480, 1.350, 465.00,36.330, 27.660, 14.830, 1.040, 4.190, 0.425, 0.101, 0.920, 1.000, 0.005, 0.060, 3.500 ]

    Training['Body'] = [44.500, 15.5, 8.1, 423, 119.5, 115, 98.2, 5.5,58, 6.40, 4, 5.7,6.6, 140,1, 10.8] 

    Test['Brain'] = [192.000,3.000,160.000,0.900,1.620,0.104,4.235]
    Test['Body'] = [180.000,25.000,169.000,2.600,11.400,2.500,50.400]




import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats



training = pd.read_csv('C:\\training.csv', index_col='Index')

test = pd.read_csv('C:\\test.csv', index_col='Index')


train_x = training['Brain']
train_y = training['Body']

slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(train_x, train_y)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))
plt.axis([-10, 600, -10, 700])

plt.plot(train_x, train_y, 'ro', color='blue')
plt.ylabel('Body')
plt.xlabel('Brain')

plt.plot(train_x, train_x*slope+intercept, 'black')

plt.plot()
plt.show()



newX = test['Body']



newY = newX * slope+intercept

print(newX)
print(newY)
print(std_err)
```

Comment: Add your code to the question, to see what you have tried, and give us a starting point to help you.

Comment: Question is edited. @Nic3500

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you not to throw any random algorithm to the data, since you have asked I would like to give my opinion. You should choose the correct algorithm to get good results. Meanwhile I give the example of linear regression here, similarly prediction can be done with other algorithms.
All the inputs are to be in an array shape.

`Test_x=np.array(Test['Brain']).reshape(-1, 1)`
`Test_y=np.array(Test['Body']).reshape(-1, 1)`
`Train_x=np.array(Train['Brain']).reshape(-1, 1)`
`Train_y=np.array(Train['Body']).reshape(-1, 1)`

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
```

`LinReg=LinearRegression()`

```
LinReg.fit(Train_x,Train_y)
LinReg.predict(Test_x)
```

Also based on your comment : Yes, you try to remove outliers from your data set then you can fit a polynomial curve. I am attaching the curve after outlier removal. You can see a non linear trend.
Fig:1 With outliers-[image]
Fig:2 Without outliers-[image]

Comment: what about to do this with logictic regression? because of distribution of data isn't proper for linear, it might be more accurate estimation of logistic one..?

Comment: I have extended the answer. If you want more help please ask.

Comment: Thank you for figures. What I need is to plot logistic regression on training dataset and to predict whole brain values in test dataset, plus r-squared (how much the model explain in percent) and confidence interval. The code I've tried is below. Gives an error "ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous' " on model.fit(X, y).

Comment: from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


training = pd.read_csv('C:\\training.csv')

Test = pd.read_csv('C:\\test.csv')


y = np.array(training['Brain']).reshape(-1,1)
X = np.array(training['Body']).reshape(-1,1)

test_y = np.array(Test['Brain']).reshape(-1, 1)
test_x = np.array(Test['Body']).reshape(-1, 1)


model = LogisticRegression()

model.fit(X, y)
model.score(X, y)

print('Coefficient: \n', model.coef_)
print('Intercept: \n', model.intercept_)

predicted=model.predict(test_y)